# Interesting behaviour when using for-in constructs in CFScript

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

I noticed something interesting when using `for-in` [constructs in cfscript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7fdf.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a0e0-7fe8): It appears that the `variable in struct` argument in the `for(in)` loop is set as an independent variable, and has no reference to its parent array key.

If you run the following code you will see the array doesn't change on output. The variable `local.i` inside the loop is being assigned the new value, but the array remains unchanged.

```
function arrayTest()
{
    local.foo = ["bar-one","bar-two", "bar-three"];

    for (local.i in local.foo)
    {
        local.i = "I am #local.i#";
        // Dump local.i; its output will be 'I am bar-[one[two]] etc...'
    }
    // Dump local.i; its output will as above

    // Dump the array; its keys remain unchanged: "bar-one, bar-two, -bar-three"
    writeDump(local.foo);
}
```

So why is this? I know arrays are passed by reference in CF, but I'm not passing an array here. I'm just using one in a `for-in` construct. There is a difference, no?

It's a bit misleading to call the argument `variable in structure.` I see `local.i` as a shortcut to `local.foo[ local.i ]`. It sounds like the var is indeed the array key and we can modify it. The solution here is to use a plain `for()` loop, instead.

Comment: You are accessing an *element* of the array, not the array object itself. In your case, a simple string. I would not expect the underlying array to change unless `i` was a complex object of some sort or something passed by reference.

Comment: @Leigh, thanks. OK, I guess I looked at `local.i` as a shortcut to `local.myArray[ key ]` -- and it's not.

Comment: That is not strictly true. If `local.i` was something complex/passed by reference (like a structure) then modifying it would modify the object within the underlying array. For example with `local.foo = [{a="b"},{a="c"}];` modifying `local.i.a = "I am key #local.i.a#";` would change the results of your dump.

Comment: @Leigh, thanks for the clarification. That makes sense now. If you care to put that in an answer it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not expect the underlying array to change unless `i` was a complex object of some sort or something passed by reference. For example if foo were

```
 local.foo = [{a="b"},{a="c"}];
```

then modifying `local.i.a = "I am key #local.i.a#";` would modify the object within the array, and those changes would be reflected in your dump.

**Update:**
Ultimately this comes down to pointers or references. In *loose* terms, `local.i` is just a pointer to objects within the array. So resetting `local.i` just points *that* variable at some other object in memory. It has no impact on the array. Notice the change in hashcode value?

```
// example
local.foo = [ "bar-one" ];
for (local.i in local.foo)
{
    WriteOutput("local.i (before) =#local.i.hashCode()#<br>"); //-335192660
    WriteOutput("local.foo[1] = #local.foo[1].hashCode()#<br>");//-335192660
    local.i = "I am key #local.i#";
    WriteOutput("local.i (after) = #local.i.hashCode()#<br>"); //1075915694
}

writeDump(local.foo);
```